# Hadoop shutdown_msg

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I installed Hadoop on windows 7, and configured it to single node.

When running yarn.cmd or hdfs.cmd, I get the following message:

SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at username/ip

Thank you

Comment: Check the hadoop logs for detailed error

Comment: can you please be more specific? what is hadoop logs? @RamananR

Comment: While installing hadoop you would have set up hadoop logs location, something like `c:\hadoop\logs`. Check *.log files in that directory. When hadoop runs it will be logged in those files. You will find what's the problem in detail.